# How do I run a TSQL script that returns a value?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Am I correct in saying it is TSQL?  I am a novice at database scripting.  Is this called scripting?  I am a novice at this, really I am.

I just wrote a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.LogTable_Count

@Count INT OUT

AS

SELECT @Count = Count(ExperimentId) FROM LogTable

GO
```

I would like to test the script by calling something like:

exec logtable_count

but management studio says it expects a parameter @Count, which was not supplied.  How do I write a couple of ad hoc lines to test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Count INT

EXEC logtable_count @Count OUTPUT

SELECT @Count
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use RETURN statement to return an integer value (only one and only integer) from a stored procedure.

Your stored procedure will look a little different:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.LogTable_Count  
AS
DECLARE @Count int
SELECT @Count = Count(ExperimentId) 
FROM LogTable
RETURN @Count
GO
```

You have to call your stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @RC int
EXEC @RC=dbo.LogTable_Count
PRINT @RC --or SELECT @RC
```

Comment: Typically the return value is used (by convention mostly) for success/failure/status indicators

Answer (score 1):

Because COUNT(*) means count the number of rows in the result set. Count(ColumnName) means count the number of rows in the result set where that column is not null.

See - http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/04/14/on-counts/

Answer (score 1):

For single values like this, I prefer to use functions because you can use them in select statements:

```
print 'Creating countRows Stored Proc ...'
go
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where  name = 'countRows') drop function countRows;
go
create function dbo.countRows()
   -- **************************************************************************
   --  Procedure: countRows()
   --     Author: Ron Savage
   --       Date: 05/01/2009
   --
   --  Description:
   --  This function counts the rows in a table and returns it.
   -- **************************************************************************
   returns integer
begin
   return(select count(*) from mytable);
end
go

-- Now you can use it in a select ...
select dbo.countRows()
go

-- Or store it in a variable ...
declare @mycount integer

select @mycount = dbo.countRows()

select @mycount
go
```

like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @myout int
exec logtable_count @myout
print @myout
```

Edit: As the correct answer states, that middle line should be:

```
exec logtable_count @myout OUTPUT
```

Comment: print @myout ended up not printing anything to the "Messages" window

Answer (score 0):

You want to use

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.LogTable_Count

AS

SELECT Count(*) FROM LogTable

GO
```

Comment: great suggestion, although not exactly what I asked.  I'll upvote this answer if you can tell me why * instead of naming one of the columns.